# How to Enable Keyspace Notifications for Expired Keys using Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

Is there a way to run the following command from Spring Data Redis, possibly using `RedisTemplate`?

```
$ redis-cli config set notify-keyspace-events Ex
```

My understanding is `RedisTemplate` can run lua scripts, can the above be converted to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, turns out there's no need to run lua script:

If using non-reactive Redis connection:

```
RedisConnection conn = null;
try {
    conn = connectionFactory.getConnection();
    conn.setConfig("notify-keyspace-events", "Ex");
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

If using reactive Redis connection:

```
ReactiveRedisConnection conn = connectionFactory.getReactiveConnection();
        conn
                .serverCommands()
                .setConfig("notify-keyspace-events", "Ex")
                .filter(status -> status.equals("OK"))
                .doFinally(unused -> conn.close())
                .block(Duration.ofSeconds(5L));
```